# The probability for 4 points on a circle to be far apart "enough"

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry

Consider choosing 4 points, $(A,B,C,D)$, randomly and independently on a unit circle. What is the probability that for all permutations $(P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4)$ of $(A,B,C,D)$, $|P_1P_2|+|P_3P_4|>2$?

The original problem only asked for the probability of $(A,B,C,D).$ I have managed to examine this case for which $|AB+CD|>2$, which worked out to be: $$1-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}{\arccos(\cos{x}+2\sqrt{2-2\cos{x}}-2)dx}\approx0.739120\ldots$$

Why not add more constraints to keep the points far from each other? However, additional requirements seem to extremely complicate the problem. I know that the probability $P\approx0.397$, but I have no idea how to know more about it, even not as a closed-form expression. Hints, solutions, and approximations are appreciated.

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  Or did you make it up yourself?

Comment: @BrianTung Kind of. As said above, the original problem was on a quirky calculus quiz I got from my class, but then I decided to tweak it.

Comment: Consider changing your sums into products (of course, it's no longer the same problem) : in this way, you could take advantage of Ptolemy's theorem for inscribed quadrilaterals.